# How to apply a customized style to a custom control in code behind

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I've got a simple custom control :

```
namespace Application.Custom_Controls
{
    public class ReadOnlyTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public ReadOnlyTextBox()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ReadOnlyTextBox);
            this.IsReadOnly = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And a custom style to make the control look like a TextBlock (in App.xaml).

```
<Application 
    x:Class="Application.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"       
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:tb = "clr-namespace:Application.Custom_Controls"
    >

    <!--Application Resources-->
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ReadOnlyTextBox" TargetType="tb:ReadOnlyTextBox">
            //...
            <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="tb:ReadOnlyTextBox">
                    //...
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

But when I'm using it in my application it does'nt display at all.
It diplays as a normal TextBox if I remove `this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ReadOnlyTextBox);`.

How to apply this style to my custom control in code behind ?

By the way, this style works well in xaml with `Style="{StaticResource ReadOnlyTextBox}"`, but I can't use xaml in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
this.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["ReadOnlyTextBox"];
```

Add this line to the constructor of the `ReadOnlyTextBox`

Comment: Or for a standard control : `yourControl.Style = (Style)App.Current.Resources["x:key of your style in Application.Ressources"];`. [Source](http://squarkz.com/2011/02/wp7-windows-phone-7-dynamic-staticresource-styling-for-listbox-items-added-in-codebehind/)